How would I make this splotchy texture in blender and export it as a 2D image
I was wondering how I could recreate the green splotchy texture on the reference below and export it as a 1024x1024 image or should I say bake it?


Not sure how to get the shape, but the ribbing shouldn’t be hard to do. Basically just multiply a properly shaped gradient by 3 or 4 and then modulus it by one. Does doing this with voronoi get the effect you want?

Something like this maybe? The Noise texture before the vector math defines the "fine ripples" around the edges of the circles (use the color mix node to control the strength - tread lightly), The Voronoi Texture defines the size, amount and shape of the "circles" and the final noise texture controls both the dot size and the "wave" effect within. The bump (normal) component is mostly unnecessary, I just threw it in for effect.


OOOHHH Yeah! That's exactly what im looking for. Do you have any idea how I would turn that into a 2D texture on a 1024x1024 texture? Im not very familiar with materials, nodes and baking yet

Just put the material on a plane and bake it (there are plenty of good tutorials on baking procedural textures - like this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AioskAgcU2U&t=86s). Make sure to specify 1024x1024 when you make the image you are baking to. Don't forget to save the image after the bake.

Thank you so much! You are amazing. Have an amazing day :)))
